# SSAS- DAX funktion Lookupvalue - The Column either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table

Tags: ssas, dax, lookup, roles, row-level-security

My Team and i are currently working on RLS in a SSAS model. We have a DAX Function but it needs improvment. The filter works but he dont filter the data from the Employee table

```
=Utilization[OrganizationalStructureKey]=LOOKUPVALUE(UserSecurity[OrganizationalStructureKey],UserSecurity[DomainName],USERNAME(),UserSecurity[OrganizationalStructureKey],Utilization[OrganizationalStructureKey],UserSecurity[Role],"Departmentlead")
```

When we try to add the column "EmployeeKey" from the Employee table to  the filter  we get the error Message
*The Column either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table aviable in the current context*

```
=Utilization[OrganizationalStructureKey]=LOOKUPVALUE(UserSecurity[OrganizationalStructureKey],UserSecurity[DomainName],USERNAME(),UserSecurity[OrganizationalStructureKey],Utilization[OrganizationalStructureKey],UserSecurity[Role],"Departmentlead",Employee[EmployeeKey],Utilization[EmployeeKey])
```

But in our Table model we have a one-to-many connection between "Employee" and Utilization" so what are we doing wrong? [our table connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdiGd.png)

Comment: Try with RELATED(Employee[EmployeeKey])

Comment: As a && addition ?

Comment: No, not as &&. Just in searched condition.
Look at this video (13:15):

https://youtu.be/iJfzfYt5Qws?t=797